# How to add javascript function in angular2 project properly? Error "ReferenceError: openNav is not defined"

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular2-template

i want to create navbar component, how to add  code in my navbar.component.html? i create my angular2 project using angular CLI. Here is how my component folder structured :
[image: Here is how my navbar component folder structure]

i follow this tutorial in w3school for creating navigation menu http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp

and here is my navbar.component.html

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>
```

here is my navbar.component.css :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #818181;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

and here is my typescript file, navbar.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  constructor() { }


}
```

when i run my project, and i click on `<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>` this button, but in my firefox browser console print this error

> "ReferenceError: openNav is not defined"

so my openNav function in  is not detect as javascript function in my html right? how do i create javascript function properly in angular2?

Comment: Nothing in your code indicates you're using Angular2. Did you check some introductorial docs first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include your `openNav` and `closeNav` function in your `navbar.component.ts` file and change your html  as below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  public displayNav: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  openNav(){
    this.displayNav = true;
  }

  closeNav(){
    this.displayNav = false;
  }
}
```

navbar.component.html

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" *ngIf="displayNav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" (click)="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: i already update my code just like your answer, but it's just like nothing happened, it should show the navigation menu, what do i miss? i think it's the css is missing?

Comment: sorry my bad, i have to assign width: 100%; iny my css class